# navigation toggle is visible only on minimizing the window

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am designing a webpage using bootstrap in which was working on navigation bar where I am trying to use 3 bars button and open the menu items on button click and close doing the same using the following code

```
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>   
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
             <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Resources</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#loginModal" data-toggle="modal" >Login</a></li>

           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

using the above it displays complete navigation when the window is on maximum size and three bars are only visible when window size is reduced.
how can I make the three bars aligned to the right corner and show menu items on clicking it?

**DEMO:**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDcnr/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

From http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar:

> #### Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint
>
> The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than `@grid-float-breakpoint`, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least `@grid-float-breakpoint` in width. Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).